# how to connect to oracle 10g using visual studio 2013

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2013

I am new to oracle database, so i wanted to know how i can connect to an `oracle 10g` database using visual studio 2013.
Well i went to the server explorer and add connection where i chose the data source as `Oracle Database` and the data provider as `.NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB`.
After that on testing the connection i get the error message as-
`ORA-06413: Connection not open.`

I searched a lot but couldn't find a proper answer to this question..
Can somebody help me out please.

OK so this is what I have done till now-

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Hostel_Management_System
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=XE;Provider=SQLOLEDB;user-name=system;password=mypassword");
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show(con.State);
        }
    }
}
```

And I am getting a System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException in System.Data.dll.

Is this of any help??

[1]. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUlZc.png

Comment: Rereading your question... did you call Open on the connection you created?

Comment: yes I did try that, it is giving an argument exception in system.data.dll

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the best way to create .net apps connected to Oracle is to use ODP.net and more specifically the managed driver which is available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).

The managed driver allows you to avoid installing an Oracle client on the machine your app runs on.
Sample code partially from the [Oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/OracleConnectionClass.htm#ODPNT761):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client; 
using System.Configuration; 

class OracleConnectionSample
{
  static void Main()
  {  
    // Connect
    const string connectionStringName = ...
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].
                    ConnectionString;
    using (var con = new OracleConnection(constr))
    {
      con.Open();

      // Execute a SQL SELECT
      using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
      {
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from emp";
        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Print all employee numbers
        while (reader.Read())
        {
          Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't find a link right away otherwise I would just post it in this comment but OP might need one for 10g instead of 12g but I'm not sure.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin Client and server version can be different. More info can be found here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/faq-093106.html#DBserver

Comment: @vc74 I have installed that managed driver in my system still I cant access the 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' library

Comment: @TanujAggarwal What do you mean by 'I have installed the managed driver in my system' and 'I can't access the lib'?